# 19.04 Can't see a 5G network

Tags: networking, wireless, 19.04

Am connected to the 2.4G.

Can connect to 5G network in windows.

Have connected to this exact same 5G network in Ubuntu in the past.

5G network doesn't appear in list of networks.

Tried to forget 2.4G network and manually add 5G network as if it's hidden, it adds the network as "networkname-5G 1", and can't connect...

No idea why this could be happening.

Router is a POS, but this very device connects to the 5G, so it's an Ubuntu problem.

Connecting thru GUI.

Comment: Hi, How did you try to connect to 5G Hidden Network in Ubuntu? Via GUI or CLI??

Comment: I'm assuming you mean 5Ghz and not 5G -- they aren't the same.  It's not uncommon for 2.4Ghz to be available and 5Ghz not -- 5Ghz does not travel as far, and is more susceptible to physical interference due to the shorter wavelength.  Also make certain that all of your devices on the network can communicate on the 5Ghz band.  Not all network adapters can and most older routers cannot.  Are you 100% certain that the network you are trying to access is dual-band?

Comment: The 5G you refer to is undefined. 5th "generation" of cellular radio? According to what standards? You see, it's just utter garbage. 5G is a perfectly acceptable abbreviation for 5Ghz, and has been for ages - https://superuser.com/questions/541554/what-is-the-difference-between-2-4g-and-5g-wireless. I'm well aware of their propagation differences. This is within range of both 2.4G and 5G radios. Remember, I'm connecting to the 5G network on other devices and this very device in Windows, and this very device in Ubuntu in the past! Are you 100% sure you read and comprehended the post?

Comment: Network is NOT dual-band. There is a 5G and 2.4G network, as clearly stated above. The router is obviously dual-band, or 3/4 of what I wrote would be impossible.

Comment: SSID 2.4G is "networkname", SSID 5G is networkname-5G". They are separate. I'm not interested in setting a preference. The problem is Ubuntu doesn't see and can't connect to the 5G band, and it's clearly Ubuntu's problem, based on everything in the original statement.

Comment: It doesn't matter, because the wireless chip connects to this 5G network in windows. This is a Ubuntu problem. Please stay focused on what we know is wrong: Ubuntu can't connect to 5G network. Previous versions of Ubuntu could on this same device, Windows on this same device does, and other devices are connecting just fine.